# Multiple std::variant visit with variadic templated helper

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I am attempting to make a function that helps handling N `std::variant` types.

**Note:** I am trying to make all pathways compile time validated. So `std::optional` and `std::holds_alternative` are not viable for me.

The implementation is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
using Possible = std::variant<std::monostate, T>;

template<typename... Types>
void ifAll(std::function<void(Types...)> all, Possible<Types>&&... possibles)
{
    std::visit(
        [&](auto&&... args) {
            if constexpr ((... &&
                           std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(args)>, Types>))
            {
                return all(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "At least one type is monostate" << std::endl;
            }
        },
        possibles...);
}
```

And an example of using the function is:

```
int main()
{
    Possible<int>  a = 16;
    Possible<bool> b = true;

    ifAll([](const int& x, const bool& y)
              -> void { std::cout << "All types set!" << std::endl; },
          a,
          b);
}
```

However I get a compiler error:

```
TestFile.cc: error: no matching function for call to 'ifAll'
    ifAll([](const int& x, const bool& y)
    ^~~~~

TestFile.cc: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
    'function<void (type-parameter-0-0...)>' against '(lambda at
    TestFile.cc)'

void ifAll(std::function<void(Types...)> all, Possible<Types>&&... possibles)
    ^
```

Why does the lambda I provide not match the function signature?

**Attempted Fix 1**

I tried moving in `a` and `b` which still does not work:

```
ifAll([](const int& x, const bool& y)
              -> void { std::cout << "All types set!" << std::endl; },
          std::move(a),
          std::move(b));
```

Comment: `std::optional`?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use std::optional? That seems to work similarly to std::variant<std::monostate, T>.

Comment: `std::optional` is not type safe and is additionally not `noexcept`. I want to eliminate the possibility of runtime errors.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment `std::variant` is no more "type safe" than `std::optional`.

Comment: You're expanding Types within the template parameter list of Possible. Possible takes one template argument. That's the problem.

Comment: Eliminating `.value()` is worth the extra effort in my case. This example above is not my actual implementation. I have abstraction that removes other unsafe methods like `get`.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment How is `visit` better than `.value()`?  The only advantage I can think of is that function pointer indirection makes it slower.

Comment: Hmmm honestly I may be off base. Would still like to see what I am doing wrong above as I just want to get better at this type of template programming.

I don't want to have anything like `has_value()` that is not compile time checked. And I don't see a way to make a compile time check using optional.

Comment: I was wrong previously. I think the actual problem is that you are trying to implicitly convert a and b to xvalues... only prvalues can be implicitly converted to xvalues. You need an std::move around a and b.

Comment: Also, `optional` is `noexcept`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool

Comment: `.value()` is not noexcept. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment `value` is a convenient wrapper that is designed to throw an exception.  Just like `get`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get

Comment: Right but do you see me using `get` here? I would use `std::optional` if it provided a method for accessing storage that compile time checked all outcomes, but it does not.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment Don't `has_value` and `operator bool` both do that?  They return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yea but I cannot get access to the storage in a statically checked way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following call would work:

```cpp
int main() {
    Possible<int>  a = 16;
    Possible<bool> b = true;

    std::function<void(int, bool)> fun = [](int x, bool y) -> void {
        std::cout << "All types set!" << std::endl;
    };

    ifAll(fun,
          std::move(a),
          std::move(b));
}
```

or switch your function signature to:

```cpp
template <typename... Types>
void ifAll(std::function<void(Types...)> const& all, Possible<Types>&... possibles)
```

and then you can call it without `std::move`:

```cpp
int main() {
    Possible<int>  a = 16;
    Possible<bool> b = true;

    std::function<void(int, bool)> fun = [](int x, bool y) -> void {
        std::cout << "All types set!" << std::endl;
    };

    ifAll(fun, a, b);
}
```

Comment: Woah this totally works! I'm not sure I understand why though?

Comment: Hurricane Development It's because they removed the const&. std::function objects cannot convert to other types of std::function objects. See my answer.

Comment: There are couple of reasons. First, you are passing a function with arguments of types `int const&` and `bool const&` but your `ifAll` function expects `int` and `bool` types. Furthermore, your second argument to function `ifAll` is rvalue reference so you need to `std::move` your parameter. Or just accept const reference which would be better IMHO.

Comment: Its a templated R-value so shouldn't it be a universal reference? Looks like I forgot the `forward` on the `std::visit`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? It's a templated x-value (&&), a type of r-value, but not just any r-value. lvalues can convert to basic rvalues, but only prvalues (like literals, a.m, a+b, etc.) can be implicitly converted to xvalues. a and b are variables, so they are lvalues (they can be assigned to). Thus you need std::move or a cast to make them xvalues.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment I would suggest you a great article from Scott Meyers [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). He will explain it better than me.

Comment: On it! Thanks. (Just when I though I understood all the l-value p-value bs).

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use a function object + `std::optional`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

struct Error {};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) if_all(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    if ((args && ...)) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), *std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
        throw Error{};
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> a{5};
    std::optional<int> b{10};
    std::cout << if_all(std::plus{}, a, b) << '\n';
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hSVRspVu173nmU1G))

If you insist to use `std::variant` instead of `std::optional` (which is probably because of some misunderstandings about either of them), the idea is the same — you need to check if all arguments are "empty" first (maybe using `std::holds_alternative`), and unwrap the arguments after.

Comment: That is not acceptable. With variant, the conditions can be compile time validated. `holds_alternative` is not a compile time check, so I will not use that.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment "With variant, the conditions can be compile time validated"  No, they can't.  Variant is strictly run-time.  It is not possible to ensure variants hold a specific alternative at compile time, because this information is runtime-only.  `visit` does not do what you think.  In particular, it uses function pointers to simulate the runtime `switch`.

Comment: Yes, but you can provide what to do given all possible states of the variant (this can be compile time validated). So as long as the standard implementation you are using does not have bugs, this is essentially compile time validation. Maybe I am using compile time validated wrong, but it is sure a hell of a lot better than optionals.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment "you can provide what to do given all possible states of the variant" You can do that with `optional` too - `has_value` and `!has_value`, by testing a bool flag.  Why do you think using function pointer indirection to do the same thing is better?

Comment: `std::visit` compile time checks that you have provided pathways for all outcomes. `has_value()` does not, so if you mess up Boolean logic, the compiler will not save you. In the case of `std::visit`, it will.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment So the reason `optional` is bad is because you may potentially misuse it?  I don't get that argument, but you can easily write an equivalent of `std::visit` for `std::optional` (with the same performance cost, of course).

Comment: You can, but it would not be compile time checked that all cases are handled.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment Why not?  If it can't, then `std::visit` can't either.  Doesn't the `if_all` function template in my answer ensure that all cases are handled too?  I think I'm misunderstanding something ...

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment Does this implementation of `visit` for optional somehow "compile time checks" as you imagine `std::visit` does? https://wandbox.org/permlink/SKKeTrkwfwDdxnm5  It's gonna be very difficult to use though, since it requires you to explicitly handle `Empty_tag`s.

Comment: No. Line `15` is a conditional statement evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment `std::visit` does this at runtime too, by indexing into a runtime array.  You can take a look at its implementation.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment Here it is: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/variant#L432-L544.  Look at the array constructed in `__make_farray`.

Comment: Yea, as I said before. I am okay with that occurring in the standard implementation, bu not in my code base.

Comment: @Hurricane Of course the standard library can’t provide everything, especially not seldom-used things like this. `std::visit` is a convenience function implemented in the standard library that can be implemented by the user as well; they didn’t feel the need to do it for optional because it is easily implementable and not useful. You can always put wrapper code (which adjusts other’s code to your style) in a library and forget about it, which is something programmers do all the time. Of course, if you really want to start a programming Oulipo, then it’s fine ...

Comment: BTW, `variant` can also be (mis-)used without compile checks: `if (v.index() == 1) foo(std::get<1>(v));`

Answer (score 1):

My apologies. I believe the problem is rather twofold:

1. You do not use std::move on passing lvalues (the variables `a`, `b`) to a function taking xvalue arguments (the `Possible<Types>&&...` expansion.)
2. You try to convert `std::function<void(const int&, const int&)>` to `std::function<void(int, int)>` when passing the lambda to your function.

The compiler matches Types to (int, int) given the other arguments. It then tries  to look for a `std::function<void(int, int)>` as the first argument. Instead, it gets a function lambda of the type `void(*)(const int&, const int&)`. Thus there is a signature mismatch.

My suggestion would be to take a hint from the standard library, and instead of trying to use std::function objects of specific type, instead add a template parameter `FuncType` for the function type, and pass in the function pointer using that. I think this might be why standard algorithms take function type as a template parameter, even when they can deduce the approximate function signature that should be passed from the other template arguments.

Comment: "It then tries to look for a std::function<void(int, int)> as the first argument. Instead, it gets a function lambda of the type void(*)(const int&, const int&). Thus there is a signature mismatch."  I thought `std::function` validates the argument based on `std::is_invocable`?  `int, bool` should work for `const int&, const bool&` IIRc.

Comment: Cool tip on just templating the function type.

Answer (score 1):

`Possible<Types>&&` is actually rvalue reference, and not forwarding reference.
You have so to add overloads to handle the different cases.

```
template<F, typename... Types> void ifAll(F, const Possible<Types>&...);
template<F, typename... Types> void ifAll(F, Possible<Types>&...);
template<F, typename... Types> void ifAll(F, Possible<Types>&&...);
```

In `template<typename... Types>
void ifAll(std::function<void(Types...)>, Possible<Types>&...)`, `Types` has to be deduced twice, and so error happens when deduction mismatches.

In your case, you have first `const int&, const bool&` (Since CTAD with C++17)
and then `int, bool`. Mismatch, so the error.

Several ways to fix the issues:

- Fix call site (fragile solution):

  ```
  std::function<int, bool> f = [](const int& x, const bool& y)
                -> void { std::cout << "All types set!" << std::endl; };
  ifAll(fun, a, b); // Assuming overload with lvalue references
  ```
- Make one parameter non deducible:

  ```
  template<typename... Types>
  void ifAll(std::function<void(std::identity_type_t<Types>...)>, Possible<Types>&...)
  ```
- Add extra template parameters:

  ```
  template<typename... Args, typename... Types>
  void ifAll(std::function<void(Args...)>, Possible<Types>&...)
  ```

  Possibly with some SFINAE.
- Change completely argument (I would go for than one):

  ```
  template<F, typename... Types>
  void ifAll(F, Possible<Types>&...)
  // or even
  template<F, typename... Ts>
  void ifAll(F, Ts&&...); // Forwarding reference, no extra overloads to add.
  ```

  Possibly with some SFINAE.

Comment: You are a proponent of the final one? I think this seems like a good idea...

Comment: Yes, but for implementation, I would do something like L. F. solution. From all the combinations, only one is interesting.

Comment: I think in this scenario that does kind of make sense., but what are the drawbacks from using visit?

Comment: With single parameter, it is mostly similar to a virtual call. With several parameters, A big numbers of overloads has to be built, that number increase rapidly (`2**n` in your case, as `Possibly<T>` has 2 cases). I am fan of `std::visit`/`std::variant` which allows simple multi dispatch, and get rid of lot of `enum` and `switch`.

Comment: So do you think the `std::visit / std::variant` idiom I am using here is less performant at runtime? Or will just take longer to compile as all of the overloads must be generated?

Comment: `std::visit` has no complexity requirement for 2 or more variants :-/ But as usual with performance, we have to measure. I bet for a longer compilation, and similar or worse runtime than the `optional` way (for the all else nothing). but just a (reasonable) bet.

Answer (score 0):

As in the accepted answer, one problem is that you shouldn't have the `&&` in `Possible<Types>&&`. This means you can only accept rvalue arguments, but in your usage example, `a` and `b` are lvalues. The easiest way to deal is to use forwarding references to handle *all* cases. The other problem is that you allow `Types...` to be deduced from the `std::function` argument. It's possible for the lambda's arguments to not exactly match the `Possible`s, and so you should prevent `Types...` from being deduced from the `std::function` and only take them from the `Possible`s. The easiest way to do this is to stick some kind of type computation in the template argument in the argument type, which makes the compiler give up trying to do deduction on that argument. Sometimes, you just use a dummy `type_identity_t` function, but, here, we can do something more interesting and get both birds with one stone

```
template<typename T>
struct get_handler_argument;
template<typename T>
struct get_handler_argument<Possible<T>> { using type = T&; };
template<typename T>
struct get_handler_argument<Possible<T> const> { using type = T const&; };
template<typename T>
using get_handler_argument_t = typename get_handler_argument<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::type;

template<typename... Vars>
void ifAll(std::function<void(get_handler_argument_t<Vars>...)> all, Vars&&... possibles) {
    std::visit(
        [&](auto&&... args) {
            if constexpr ((... &&
                           std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(args)>, std::decay_t<get_handler_argument_t<Vars>>>)) {
                return all(std::forward<get_handler_argument_t<Vars>>(args)...);
            } else {
                std::cout << "At least one type is monostate" << std::endl;
            }
        },
        possibles...);
}
```

What you lose here is that you can no longer directly provide a "present" value in place of a `Possible` value without explicitly wrapping it in the `Possible` constructor. This is no loss; just capture it instead of passing it. What you gain is that you can use a function call or what-have-you to initialize the `Possible`s, instead of having to save them in variables manually first. Your example works as-is with this definition, unlike the currently accepted answer.